# Date Picker - With Accessibility Features - Compatible to IE11 and up

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to find a Datepicker that:

- Works in all browsers (IE11 and up)
- Works on a textbox (no input type "date")
- Is accessibility friendly (Has a textbox validation mask)
- Renders the same way on all browsers

Textbox Mask and Datepicker can be separate.

I've tried: 
- jQueryUI (custom downloads seem broken)
- Bootstrap Datepicker (broke on IE11)

Please help finding a library that has the above criteria, can have jquery as required library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest try to refer to an example below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker functionality</title>
      <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://rawgit.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/master/dist/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
    <script>
         $(function() {
            $("#datepicker-1").datepicker().mask('99/99/9999');
         }); 
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Enter Date: <input type = "text" id = "datepicker-1" placeholder="MM / DD / YYYY"></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11 browser and Google Chrome browser:

[image]

Further, you can try to modify the sample as per your own requirements.